# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x697e0aea, pid=11340, tid=11292

Tags: java

I am getting following error when I try to run my Spring+hibernate application in Netbeans 8.0. 
Same code is working fine on other machine

By reading various post, I tried below mentioned points but all in vain.
    1.) Installed new version of java but no help
    2.) Created new work space but no help.
    3.)Installed IDE but no help.

```
Error Log

>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
>  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x697e0aea, pid=11340, tid=11292
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
> Problematic frame:
> C  [atioglxx.dll+0x7b0aea]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
> E:/*path*/hs_err_pid11340.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>
```

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x16e5e800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=11292, stack(0x19150000,0x191a0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000100, EBX=0x00000100, ECX=0x00000040, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x1919e270, EBP=0x1919e278, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x223f0fe8
EIP=0x697e0aea, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x1919e270)
0x1919e270:   00000001 223f0fe8 00000000 691d4a88
0x1919e280:   223f0fe8 00000000 00000100 19cd0ad8
0x1919e290:   1919e308 69ad7640 00000100 00000100
0x1919e2a0:   776d3664 00000100 223f0fe8 00000100
0x1919e2b0:   00000000 00000000 00000001 00000004
0x1919e2c0:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000
0x1919e2d0:   691d7766 00000100 00000100 00000100
0x1919e2e0:   00000000 00000000 00000001 503721c2 

Instructions: (pc=0x697e0aea)
0x697e0aca:   fe 5e 5f 75 08 5e 5f 5d e9 12 5b 00 00 f7 c7 03
0x697e0ada:   00 00 00 75 15 c1 e9 02 83 e2 03 83 f9 08 72 2a
0x697e0aea:   f3 a5 ff 24 95 04 0c 7e 69 90 8b c7 ba 03 00 00
0x697e0afa:   00 83 e9 04 72 0c 83 e0 03 03 c8 ff 24 85 18 0b 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000100 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000100 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000040 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x1919e270 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x16e5e800
EBP=0x1919e278 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x16e5e800
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x223f0fe8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x19150000,0x191a0000],  sp=0x1919e270,  free space=312k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [atioglxx.dll+0x7b0aea]


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8329320k(2834288k free), swap 16656784k(10149956k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.5-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_05-b13), built on Mar 18 2014 01:14:47 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Mon Jul 27 10:17:26 2015
elapsed time: 76 seconds




Kindly help.
```

Comment: please refer hs_err_pid11340.log

Comment: You should report the bug on http://bugs.java.com/

Comment: already reported 3 days ago

Comment: User Access Control -->is already in Never Notify State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****ISSUE RESOLVED:****

It was actually a hardware compatibility issue. THE GRAPHICS CARD INSTALLED on my machine was not supporting system(machine) configuration. I removed the card & my spring+hibernate application runs fine. pheww...great relief. :) :)